# Android use ActivityForResult in ArrayAdapter with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog

In my `ArrayAdapter` I have an `AlertDialog` with a button. Now I want to use `ActivityForResult` for that. In this simple code I can use an `Intent` to view the other `Activity` but I can not get passed data from it in `ArrayAdapter`.

```
public class AdapterReceiveSMS extends ArrayAdapter<ReceivedItemStructure> {
    private myDialog dialog;

    public AdapterReceiveSMS(ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.rsms, array);
    }

        /* ----- Clicking on Forward Button ----- */
        forward_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        G.activityDialogContext);
                View vForward = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.forward, null);
                builder.setView(vForward);
                final AlertDialog sms_dialog = builder.create();
                sms_dialog.show();

                from_file.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View v) {
                        Intent fileBrowser = new Intent(G.activity,ActivityFileBrwoser.class);
                        G.activity.startActivityForResult ( fileBrowser, 1 );
                    }
                } );

        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: first u understnad Activityforresult is the part of Activty and Adapter is tha part of multipal data contant so first u understaund what u want to do

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar yes thats right. my quastion is can i use that in arrayAdapter? i can use that into activity but i need to have that into arrayAdapter. can i have this ability?

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult in an overridden method of Activity class and called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.”

you started the activity using this code

```
G.activity.startActivityForResult ( fileBrowser, 1 );
```

you must put your onActivityResult method in your calling activity ( I mean activity in which you are creating the object of AdapterReceiveSMS class. )

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a callback method to a class and hope that the system calls it. onActivityResult belongs to your Activity which then can pass the information to your adapter.